# For loop freezes my program

Tags: java, for-loop, freeze, sudoku

I'm trying to make a 9 X 9 Sudoku random generated grid but I'm having a problem. Every time I run the program, it always freezes and only displays like more or less 5 rows of random generated numbers. I don't get problems with the 4 X 4 and 6 X 6 grids, only with the 9 X 9. I don't know why it keeps freezing. I hope someone can help me. Here is my code.

```
public class Sudoku9x9
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[][] sudoku = new int[9][9];
        int rnum = 0;

        for(int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
            {
                boolean checkWhile = false;
                while(checkWhile == false)
                {
                    rnum = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
                    if(CheckRow(a, b, sudoku, rnum) && CheckCol(a, b, sudoku, rnum)))
                    {
                        sudoku[a][b] = rnum;
                        checkWhile = true;
                    }
                }

                System.out.print(rnum + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        for(int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
            {
                System.out.print(sudoku[a][b] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static boolean CheckRow(int a, int b, int[][] sudoku, int rnum)
    {
        boolean check = true;
        for(int c = b; c > 0; c--)
        {
            if(sudoku[a][c - 1] == rnum)
            {
                check = false;
            }
        }

        return check;
    }

    public static boolean CheckCol(int a, int b, int[][] sudoku, int rnum)
    {
        boolean check1 = true;
        for(int c = a; c > 0; c--)
        {
            if(sudoku[c - 1][b] == rnum)
            {
                check1 = false;
            }
        }

        return check1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug and check which line causing the delay.

Comment: What are the `boolean`s returned by the calls to the method `CheckCol`?

Comment: Sai Gowthami: Okay I'll try that.

Comment: Tactical advice: never compare boolean expressions with `true` or `false`

Comment: Christian: The booleans in the CheckRow & CheckCol methods are for checking if the random generated number is in that row/column. If it is, then CheckRow/CheckCol will return false, else it will return true. Then the while(checkWhile == false) loop will continue to loop and generate another random number for the CheckRow/CheckCol to check.

Comment: JensG: Okay I will remember that from now on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is slow because when your program fill up most of the Sudoku, it is hard to generate a proper random int to fill next slot, so `rnum` will be generated once and once again and many repeated integers are generated. For example, if there is only one number can make checkRow and checkCol true, it's 1/9 probability to generate it! What's worse, your program will fall into unsolvable situation!!!

So you need a backtracing program, similar to the eight queen problem. Here is my code:

```
static int[][] sudoku = new int[9][9];

public static boolean CheckRow(int a, int b, int[][] sudoku, int rnum)
{
    boolean check = true;
    for(int c = b; c > 0; c--)
    {
        if(sudoku[a][c - 1] == rnum)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return check;
}

public static boolean CheckCol(int a, int b, int[][] sudoku, int rnum)
{
    boolean check1 = true;
    for(int c = a; c > 0; c--)
    {
        if(sudoku[c - 1][b] == rnum)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return check1;
}

public static boolean fill(int a, int b) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rnum = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    boolean checkWhile = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9 && !checkWhile; i++) {
        if(CheckRow(a, b, sudoku, rnum) && CheckCol(a, b, sudoku, rnum))
        {
            sudoku[a][b] = rnum;
            if(a == 8 && b == 8) return true;
            if(b == 8) checkWhile = fill(a+1,0);
            else checkWhile = fill(a,b+1);
        }
        if(rnum == 9) rnum = 1;
        else rnum += 1;

    }
    return checkWhile;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    fill(0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.print(sudoku[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh okay I get what you're trying to say. :) I tried your code but I'm having a problem with 1 thing, the `sudoku[a][b] = rnum;`. It won't store the `rnum` in the array but if I replace `sudoku[a][b] = rnum;` with `System.out.print(rnum + " ");`, it runs perfectly.

Comment: @quevinrai you can see my edited post. I give a backtracing version. But it will take a long time, for each slot, it will try 9 times at most

Comment: @quevinrai I think a much better way to generate a sudoku is give a sudoku, for example 1-9;2-9,1;3-9,1-2..., and generate two random int, for example 1 and 2, then exchange all 1 and 2 in the sudoku. You can generate many pairs of number and make the sudoku more random feel.

Comment: Okay I will try your suggestion. :) I am trying your backtracking version and I'm waiting for it to display an output but it still won't display.

Comment: @quevinrai sorry, I make a typo when edit it :( You can try newest edit, not so long indeed :)

Comment: Cool it worked! :D Thank you so much! Wow I really have so much to learn. I'm gonna study your backtracking version so that next time I can do it on my own. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Oh I want to ask a question. It is bad to keep pressing the run button repetitively, right?

Comment: @quevinrai well, I dont think it's a good/bad problem. If you run your program once and it doesnt work(throws exception, wrong results, blocks or something else), you should think about how to debug it instead of run it again and again. If you try your best and cannot make it, you can come to stackoverflow for help :)

Comment: Okay I will learn about debugging. Yeah I will always go here if I need any help. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

One method I could spot to avoid unnecessary checking is to change ur checking methods to return once a false is found;

```
public static boolean CheckCol(int a, int b, int[][] sudoku, int rnum)
    {
        boolean check1 = true;
        for(int c = a; c > 0; c--)
        {
            if(sudoku[c - 1][b] == rnum)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return check1;
    }
```

for row as well.

Read locoyou's answer. Also, your program has no backtracking capability, it might come to a place where your sodoku is unsolvable, then you'll need to backtrack. One more important element of sudoku you might want to check for is to check for the 3x3 box which the number resides in.

Comment: Okay thank you I will remember that. :) Yeah I wanted to try backtracking but I sort of got confused with the algorithm but after I solve my program, I will learn backtracking. :)